# Block ips with iptables from list with comments

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have the following ip blocking list:

```
123.151.149.222#China Telecom TIANJIN, CN
91.188.124.0/23#Hosting Company, PL
134.145.0.0/16#Shell Information Technology International, CN
134.146.0.0/15#Shell Information Technology International, CN
```

I want to block those ips with iptables like this:

```
BANNED_IPS=$(egrep -v -E "^#|^$" /etc/blocked.ips.list)

for ip in $BANNED_IPS
do
    iptables -A INPUT -s $ip -m comment --comment "$comment" -j DROP
done
```

Example: where **$ip** should be `123.151.149.222` and **$comment** should be `China Telecom TIANJIN, CN`. And, yes, I know the above script doesn't work. I would like the script to be like the one above.

**Question:** How can i achieve this?

Comment: why negative and close vote???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
IFS='#'
egrep -v '^#|^$' /etc/blocked.ips.list |
    while read ip comment
    do
        $BANNED_IPS =A INPUT -s $ip -m comment --comment "$comment" -j DROP
    done
```

Explanation:

```
IFS='#'
```

changes the shell's field separator, used by `read` and word-splitting after variable expansion.

Comment: I also restored the $IFS variable after the script execution.

Comment: You don't need to do that, it's only being set within the shell of the script, not your interactive shell.

Comment: I'm using it again (the $IFS) below, that's why I got the old value at the beginning of the script and reset it as it was.